# Patches of weedy grass in lawn

Tags: lawn, grass, weeds

I have at least a dozen areas in my lawn that have these longer patches of grass. It's clearly a different species than the rest of my lawn, but I don't know why it keeps popping up.  It grows 2x/3x faster than the rest of my lawn, so it makes the lawn look sloppy within less than a week after mowing.  (I live in Ohio)

I had weed/crabgrass control applied to my lawn earlier in the year -- should this have been killed by a weed killer?  Any other thoughts on how to quickly eliminate it?[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is nutsage they grow super fast and aggressive don't think the regular weed killers work on this you will need something like this one....good luck
[https://www.amazon.com/dp/B0060N8TG8/ref=cm_sw_r_cp_apa_glt_fabc_7NW1NND3KXA77HANEB1N?_encoding=UTF8&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0060N8TG8)

Comment: I believe that is a sedge, not actually grass, so grass killers do not work on it.

Comment: The product listed is not listed as effective on nutsedge, according to Clemson University. See here for more details: https://hgic.clemson.edu/factsheet/nutsedge/